# Filter roads that will be used when calculating the route

Tags: ios, swift, here-api

I’m developing an application using HERE SDK for iOS and I encountered a problem.

The problem is with the NMACoreRouter class.
When calculating the route from point A to point B I would like the results to include just the roads I defined. It should not return results which include roads that are not included. It’s kind of filtering function. It is finding fastest route from point A to point B, but using just certain roads (which I can define, similar to the function that excludes the highway from the results, this would include just the roads I defined).
I looked into the documentation, but haven’t found anything that could do this.
I have a few ideas how to solve this, but nothing really appealing.

a) use calculateRoute method and then compare NMARoute.geometry if the route is using roads that are included in my list. If not exclude this route, and so on..

b) add some waypoints (beside start and stop) when calculating the route. The problem here is, that when using more than two waypoints, it only returns one route. Another problem is that I would have to determine on which part of the road are which waypoints, and then add them before calculating, because of the waypoints limit (I think it's 128), and if the route should be really long it will be the problem.

So I’m interested if maybe you have any suggestion how to solve this, more elegantly (faster, better..). Because obviously, these solutions are far from perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Accroding to documentation for Premium SDK `NMACoreRouter` supports only routes with a maximum of 32 waypoints.

`NMACoreRouter` is not providing any filtering mechanism based on actual roads. However, you can provide `NMARoutingMode` and `NMARoutingOption` to specifiy that you want to exclude certain types of roads, e.g. no toll roads or no highways.

I cannot think of a use case that may require a list of mandatory roads. The closest use case is to use waypoints. So, if you must include a certain road, then simply add a waypoint that lies on that road.

I guess the number of route alternatives depends on how granular you define the waypoints. Otherwise I suggest to enforce alternatives by passing in a different set of waypoints.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not solve my problem. I know abut NMARoutingMode and NMARoutingOption but that does not help. I need the possible routes to be predefined. So user can choose one of the predefined routes.

Comment: I am afraid there are no better alternatives to what you have already described in your question. However, the opposite seems do-able: When looking at `NMADynamicPenalty` class it offers to add banned areas or even banned RoadElements. Also, I'd like to add that the SDK distinguishes between stops and waypoints. While you can add only a maximum of 32 waypoints, you can specify up to 128 stops.

Comment: I looked into the NMADynamicPenalty class and it has filters to ban the roads and areas but not to allow-only these roads, maybe it would be possible to achieve what I need through this but very difficult. Also, it seems that Custom Route Extension could do the job, but it seems that it is not available on iOS platform. The problem is that 128 stops are not enough.